QGIS Server GetPrint multiprocessing documentation?
Where can we find better documention for QGIS Server GetPrint multiprocessing. Especially regarding the multiprocessing for generate multiple pdf at the same time.
I am currently running a QGIS Server and a Java service that collects and constructs requests for a getprint operation. And I am trying to figure out how to parallelising the generation like in this topic:
Python and QGIS multiprocessing documentation?
Here is the Dockerfile that I am using for QGIS Server :
FROM debian:bookworm-slim

ENV LANG=en_EN.UTF-8

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests --allow-unauthenticated -y \
        gnupg \
        ca-certificates \
        wget \
        locales \
    && localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8 \
    && mkdir -m755 -p /etc/apt/keyrings \
    && wget -O /etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg https://download.qgis.org/downloads/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg] https://qgis.org/debian bookworm main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests --allow-unauthenticated -y \
        qgis-server \
        spawn-fcgi \
        xauth \
        xvfb \
    && apt-get remove --purge -y \
        gnupg \
        wget \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN useradd -m qgis

And here how I start it :
docker run -d --rm --name qgis-server --net=qgis --hostname=qgis-server -v $(pwd)/data:/data:ro -p 5555:5555 -e "QGIS_PROJECT_FILE=/data/QGIS-project/qgis.qgs" qgis-server

Here is my configuration for my nginx Docker :
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name _;
  location / {
    root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
  }
  location /qgis-server {
    proxy_buffers 16 16k;
    proxy_buffer_size 16k;
    gzip off;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass qgis-server:5555;
  }
}

And how I start it :
docker run -d --rm --name nginx --net=qgis --hostname=nginx -v $(pwd)/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro -p 8080:80 nginx:1.13

And here the script that I run at the start of QGIS Server :
#!/bin/bash

[[ $DEBUG == "1" ]] && env

exec /usr/bin/xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-num=1 /usr/bin/spawn-fcgi -p 5555 -n -d /home/qgis -- /usr/lib/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi

